# Google Maps V3: turning landmark infowindows off

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I remove the info-windows but keep the actual landmark visible? I just don't want the actual info-window to appear when the landmark is clicked because I have markers around landmarks and sometimes the landmarks are accidentally clicked instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are called `clickableIcons`.
To turn off the `InfoWindows`, set the `MapOption` `clickableIcons: false`.

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)
:

> **clickableIcons** | Type:  boolean
>   When false, map icons are not clickable. A map icon represents a point of interest, also known as a POI. By default map icons are clickable.

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      clickableIcons: false
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```